# Storing output from an external file in a variable

Tags: c, parsing, stdio

I am new to C and this is really giving me trouble.  Note that I've spent 10 days searching, reading and trying.

What I have...

- an external C program that generates random unsigned integers on command
- numbers are generated in pairs (key/value)
- For example, from command line I could simply type `./getNum -g 100` to generate a list of 100 key/value pairs - g [INT 1] [INT 2]
- I have my program which stores key/value pairs in an array

My Question: I've heard that I could use the following command to get the output of integers from the external file into my program for storage:

```
./myProgram < file_with_command.txt
```

Note: file_with_command.txt contains the following command: `./getNum -g 100`

I saw the below code on a previous post but I wasn't able to get things to work.

```
int main(void) {

    char *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    int length = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (length == bufferSize)
        {
            bufferSize *= 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, bufferSize);
        }

        buffer[length++] = c;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        putchar(buffer[j]);
    }

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the generated values from the file_with_command and into variables to store into my array?

Any help would be appreciated and the simplest solution is the best.

Comment: what is your issue with the above code?

Comment: "I've heard that I could use the following command to get the output of integers from the external file into my program for storage" -- you heard wrong, or else misinterpreted what you heard.  The command you presented will not have the effect of running the program named inside the text file.  It is appropriate for feeding the *output* of such a program, that has been captured in that file, to commad `./myProgram`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon my comment, you wrote

> My Question: I've heard that I could use the following command to get
>   the output of integers from the external file into my program for
>   storage:
>
> ./myProgram < file_with_command.txt
>
> Note: file_with_command.txt contains the following command: ./getNum
>   -g 100

The command you presented is not appropriate for your purpose.  It redirects the *contents* of file `file_with_command.txt` to the standard input of `./myProgram`, but the contents do not constitute a list of numbers.  Rather, they are a command by which you want to generate numbers.  If you record the output of that command in such a file then you could use the result as you propose:

```
./getNum -g 100 > file_with_command.txt
./myProgram < file_with_command.txt
```

If you want to use the same list of numbers for each run of `./myProgram`, then you can and should populate the file (via the first command) only once.

If you want to generate a new list of numbers for each run of `./myProgram` then you'll need to run `getNum` each time, but then it would be cleaner and more conventional to pipe the numbers into your program:

```
./getNum -g 100 | ./myProgram
```

Comment: Great feedback John. I think that my reference to the section of code that I saw in a post may not have been good.  Never the less, you cleared most things up for me. I have one other question.  Actually I do want to redirect the contents of the file - file_with_command.txt to the standard input of ./myProgram.  In doing this, I should be able to directly call the command from with myProgram and read the contents of the stream via popen(). Am I correct? And if so, my biggest challenge would be how to read the input stream. If this is straight forward, now worries. I'll Google around.

Comment: Why are you making it hard, @UberDataGeek?  Since you're relying on I/O redirection anyway, just use it appropriately; the result will be more flexible.  But yes, you *can* read the command from the standard input (via redirection from the file), or by opening the file directly and reading it, or even from command-line arguments.  Having done so, yes, you can use `popen()` to run the command and read its output into the program.  To read the command from the standard input, I would suggest the `fgets()` function.

Comment: Ok @JohnBollinger, one final question regarding fgets. You have been a BIG help.  If I'm using fgets to read strings, I have no problem. But how would I use fget to obtain a single character char - g and the a pair of integers. The the program streams in as:

g [INT 1] [INT 2]

To get the exact char I need to do:
char the_call[1];
fgets(the_call,1,stdin);

This would allow me to, if I wanted, print the following to screen:
printf("The call is, %s\n",the_call);

However, how would I get the pair of integers in the same exact manner. I apologize for the elementary question.

Thanks

Comment: @UberDataGeek, again, why are you making it hard?  If you plan to run the command via `popen()` then you don't need to parse it into pieces -- `popen()` takes a whole command as a single string.  If indeed you need to parse it then there are innumerable ways to do so.  In fact, there are too many for me to suggest one to you without taking the details of your needs into account.  But please don't go into that, for your line of inquiry has already left the actual question far behind.  Research the issue, and post a new question if necessary.

Comment: My apologies for bothering you with this trivial matter @JohnBollinger. Thanks for your help.